# How to call a function in Perl script after performing SSH?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, subroutine

I am creating a perl script in which I have to ssh multiple servers from same script and perform same commands on all these remote servers.
Right now I am using "If loop" and call all other servers from this script and perform command on them.
I want to create a function with these set of commands, that I need to perform on these different servers.

```
if($random_number==1){
use Net::SSH::perl
use lib qw("user/share/perl5/");
my $hostname = "10.*.*.*";
my $username = "root";
my $password = "root\@123";
my $cmd1  = "ls /home/ashish/"
my $cmd2 = "netstat -na | grep *.*.*.*;
$ssh->login("$username" , "$password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$smd1" && "$cmd2");
print $stdout;
}
```

the above commands after if syntax needs to be repeated for different servers.
want to use a function call.

Comment: What is the random number for?

Comment: 1) 'if' is not a loop
2) Start with some basic perl/general programming toutorials

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question :-)

Comment: use [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH::Parallel);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with general programming toutorials, then do it like:

```
use Net::SSH::perl;
use strict;
use warnings;    

my @servers = (
    {
        hostname => 'somehost1',
        username => 'someuser1',
        password => 'somepass1',
        commands => ['somecmd11','somecmd12'],
    },
    {
        hostname => 'somehost2',
        username => 'someuser2',
        password => 'somepass2',
        commands => ['somecmd21','somecmd22'],
    },
# ...
);

do_something_on_remote_servers_one_by_one( @servers );
exit(0);




sub do_something_on_remote_servers_one_by_one { 
    my (@servers) = @_;

    foreach my $server (@servers) {
        my $ssh = Net::SSH::perl->new($server->{hostname});
        $ssh->login($server->{username}, $server->{password});
        my $cmd_string = join(' & ', @{ $server->{commands} } );
        my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd_string);
        print $stdout;
    }
}
```

After that, you can think about executing commands in paralell.